# How we know that Quran was not altered during the times of revelation?

Tags: quran, history, revelation

Salam Alaikum,

I was speaking yesterday with an atheist, and the main discussion was about "How can you be sure that Quran is 100% not altered between the moment when Djebril Alayhi Salam gave the message to Prophet Mohamed Salla Allah aalayhi wa salam, and when Prophet Alayhi sallat wa salam gave it to his camarads" ?

How to be sure that Mohamed did not forget even one word..etc

My answer was : If he forgot something, it was easy for Allah to give corrections !

Can someone give me additionnal "proofs" or answers please

Answer (score 5):

In my view, questions of these types are internally inconsistent.

1) Does the inquirer believe in Allah, and that Allah did send the Revelation through Angel Gabriel to Prophet Muhammad (peace and blessings be upon him)? If not, the question is pointless.

2) Does the inquirer believe in Allah, and that Allah did send the Revelation through Angel Gabriel to Prophet Muhammad (peace and blessings be upon him)? If so, most certainly, the All Mighty will make sure that the Message is ungarbled.

3) Still, in my view, and this is just a view, the Holy Quran contains various [hash codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) (for example various discoveries with respect to number 7 and 19). To me, such findings prove that the Message is ungarbled. (Just like a tiniest change alters the hash code, the tiniest change in Quran breaks many of those things with respect to those numbers. And mind you, they are just what we know for now, there are potentially thousands of such things we are not aware of.)

Comment: 4) And we still have earliest copies of Qur'an that we can verify with contemporary copies (if necessary). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topkapi_manuscript

Comment: 1) and 2) are philosophically correct, but the challenge is rhetorical or designed to instil disbelief, not logical.

Answer (score 0):

Because there was an like an organized of group of sahabas like Usthman,Abdullah Ibn Masood Etc. who knew the Quran from the heart or recited it very often and organized to collect the verses and collections to put it in Standardized version we have today.

Comment: Salam, thank you for your answer, but my question is about the moment prophet is giving the message to sahabas, no word was missed ? (in my point of view, nothing was missed)

Comment: it is also worth mentioning that the holy prophet had a strong dictation on how the quran should be wrote because he knew it was the holy book of allah (S.W.T) he had this dictation durning his life time.

Comment: ANOTHER FACT is the ALLAH (S.W.T) is the protector of the quran himself allah has said in the verse "We have, Without doubt,Sent down the message and we assurely guard it (From Corruption).15:9